# Distributed RabbitMQ Nodes don't recognize each other

Tags: erlang, distributed, rabbitmq, connectivity

I'm working on a RabbitMQ distributed POC and I'm stuck at the basics of clustering the nodes.
I'm trying to follow the rabbit's [tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) on clustering so this is my reference.
After installing erlang (R14B04) and rabbit (2.8.2-1) I've copied the `.erlang.cookie` file contents from one node to the other two.
I wasn't sure about how to get erlang to notice this change to I had to restart the machines themselves (pretty brute force but I don't know erlang at all).
In addtion I opened in iptables 4369 and 5 additional ports for communications and placed under 
`/usr/lib64/erlang/bin/sys.config` the following config:

```
{kernel,[{inet_dist_listen_min, XX00},{inet_dist_listen_max,XX05}]}]
```

Then another restart (dumb I know) to verify erlang takes these into consideration but still when I run:

```
rabbitmqctl cluster rabbit@HostName1
```

I get:

```
Clustering node rabbit@HostName2 with [rabbit@HostName1] ...
Error: {no_running_cluster_nodes,[rabbit@HostName1],
                                 [rabbit@HostName1]}
```

There is a chance my fiddling with the erlang.cookie or with the ports did not succeed but I don't know how to check them. I tried typing `erl` in the cmd and then `erl_epmd:names()` or other commands to get more information but I'm probably way off in erlang land.

Would truly appreciate any help

**Update:**
I tried pinging two erlang nodes manually and got `pang` back.
I did the following:
  Connected to two nodes, stopped rabbitmq (wasn't sure if needed but to be sure), started erlang like so (`erl -sname dilbert` and `erl -sname dilbert2`) when the erlang command line started i ran `node().` on each of them and got `dilbert@HostName1` and `dilbert2@HostName2` respectively. I then tried to run `net_adm:ping('dilbert').` and `net_adm:ping('dilbert@HostName1').` with the single quote and without them from both nodes (changed names of course) and got on all 8 cases `pang`.
When I ran `nodes().` on one of the machines I got back an empty array.
I've also tried to allow all traffic in the firewall ([script](http://pastebin.com/KLre0vXp)) and then try to run the above   commands (don't worry they're back on now) and still got back `pang`.
**Update2:**
For some reason I had cookies mismatch which I needed to resolve (thanks @kjw0188 for the suggestion [I ran `erlang:get_cookie().` in the erlang command line]).
This did not help and I needed to stop iptables completely (not sure why but I'll figure it soon) and load the erlang node with `-name dilbert@my-ip` because my rackspace servers have no dns-name. This finally enabled me to get a pong and see the nodes see each other (`nodes().` returns a non-empty array after the ping).
The problem I'm facing now is how to instruct RabbitMQ to use -name instead of -sname when starting erlang.

Comment: Did you see if you can start erl nodes on each machine, and see if they can ping each other?

Comment: @kjw0188 Haven't tried it yet (erlang noob). Do you know how I can check to see that the current node is not running? I think RabbitMQ starts a node when it loads so I'll stop it but I want to verify no node is running before I try your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to take down rabbit, but if you want to, you can try stopping the service `sudo /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server stop`

Comment: @kjw0188 Still no luck, please see my update above. Thanks

Comment: Do the cookies match? Try `erlang:get_cookie().` on `dilbert` and `dogbert`, or setting the cookie manually with the `-setcookie` command line option.  If they still can't ping each other, it seems like erlang can't find the other nodes for some reason.  Are the hosts reachable by normal `ping`?  Use the hostname for the machines for the ping, not the IP address.

Comment: @kjw0188 Awkwardly enough one of the cookies didn't match. For some reason I have multiple cookies on each node (might be related to rabbitMQ) and one of the cookies wasn't a match. The bad news are that even after I fixed that I still get back `pang`. I had a problem pinging between the nodes not with the IP and I think this has to do with the fact that they're Rackspace hosted. I'll try to verify it with them and update here once there is anything new. Thanks for all your help and patience.

Comment: I just want to add, I am working on Windows and was also having issues with the clustering.  I kept getting the message "TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed".  Turns out, the hostname is case-sensitive even in Windows so instead of rabbit@rabbitmq_node1 I had to put rabbit@RABBITMQ_NODE1 because that's how it appears in %COMPUTERNAME%

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I had multiple issues with connecting my two RabbitMQ nodes-
I'll add that my nodes are hosted on rackspace, and so don't have a default exposable hostname, and require iptables since there is no DMZ or built in security group concept like amazon.

**Problems:**
1. Cookie- Not sure how or why but I had multiple instances of `.erlang.cookie` (in `/root`, in my home directory and in `/var/lib/rabbitmq/`) I kept only the one in rabbitmq and verified all nodes have the same cookie.
2. IPTables- In order for the nodes to communicate I needed to open the `epmd` port and the range of ports for the actual communication `inet_dist_listen_min` `inet_dist_listen_max`.

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport ${epmd} -s ${otherNode} -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport ${inet_dist_listen_min}:${inet_dist_listen_max} -s ${otherNode} -j ACCEPT
```

`empd` is the usuall 4369 port and for the other range use whatever range you want.
`${otherNode}` is the ip of my other node.
I also needed to configure erlang through rabbitmq to use these ports (see config file at end)
3. HostName- Seeing as I don't have a hostname I needed to edit the rabbit scripts to use `-name` and not `-sname` (the first tells erlang to take the whole name, the latter stands for short name and thus appends an @ symbol and the hostname).
This was accomplished by editing:
`/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmqctl`
Added at the beginning the definition of the `RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS` property

```
DEFAULT_NODE_IP_ADDRESS=auto
DEFAULT_NODE_PORT=5672
[ "x" = "x$RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS" ] && RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS=${NODE_IP_ADDRESS}
[ "x" = "x$RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT" ] && RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=${NODE_PORT}

[ "x" = "x$RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS" ] && [ "x" != "x$RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT" ] && RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS=${DEFAULT_NODE_IP_ADDRESS}
[ "x" != "x$RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS" ] && [ "x" = "x$RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT" ] && RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=${DEFAULT_NODE_PORT}
```

and in the actual erl command I changed
`-sname ${RABBITMQ_NODENAME} \` to
`-name ${RABBITMQ_NODENAME}@${RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS}\`.
This made rabbitmq listen only on the specified ip address (specified in the config file at the end) and load with that ip instead of the usuall hostname.

edited `/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server`
Changed the actual erl command from `-sname ${RABBITMQ_NODENAME} \` to `-name ${RABBITMQ_NODENAME}@${RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS}`\

Added a rabbit conf (`/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf`) file with-

```
#the ip address which rabbit should use, this is to limit rabbit to only use internal rackspace communication and not publicly accessible ports  
NODE_IP_ADDRESS=myIpAdress  
#had to change the nodename becaue otherwise rabbitmq used rabbit@Hostname and not only rabbit  
NODENAME=myCompany
#This instructed rabbit to instruct erlang which ports it should use for its communications with other nodes  
export SERVER_ERL_ARGS="$SERVER_ERL_ARGS -kernel inet_dist_listen_min somePort -kernel inet_dist_listen_max someOtherBiggerPort"
```

Some resources which helped me along the way:
[RabbitMQ Clustering Guide](http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html)
[Clustering RabbitMQ servers for High Availability](http://dudefrommangalore.wordpress.com/2009/08/22/clustering-rabbitmq-servers-for-high-availability/)
[rabbitmq-env.conf(5) manual page](http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmq-env.conf.5.man.html)
[Node communication by public IP address erlang mailing list](http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/Node-communication-by-public-IP-address-td2089236.html) (The middle post)
[Configuring RabbitMQ Cluster on Cloud](http://suniluiit.wordpress.com/2010/10/26/configuring-rabbitmq-cluster-on-cloud/)

Hope this will help anyone else.

**EDIT:**
Not sure how I was mistaken but it seemed my erlang-rabbit port instructions were not taken into consideration or were not enough. Ended up having to allow all communications between the two nodes...

Answer (score 3):

One thing to really watch out for is whitespace of any kind in the erlang cookie file, especially line breaks AFTER the contents of the cookie.  So long as both are identical, things are okay, but when one has a line break and the other doesn't, thing won't work.

Answer (score 2):

**Background:** I was facing the same issue while setting up Rabbitmq cluster. I was using 2 docker containers running on my host-machine, which is equivalent to 2 separate nodes and I could not create a cluster of these two.

**Solution:** 1. Make sure you have same erlang cookie on all your cluster nodes, the default location is `/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie`. This file is used for authentication, so make sure, you have it same on all the nodes. After changing the .erlang.cookie ***restart your rabbitmq service.***

2. Make sure that nodes are accessible from one other, use ping or telnet to check the connection.
3. Check that /etc/hosts have correct entries, for example if rabbit2 wants to join cluster rabbit1, /etc/hosts of rabbit2 should contain.

   ```
   172.68.1.6      rabbit1
   172.68.1.7      rabbit2
   ```

Now stop service using `$rabbitmqctl stop_app` followed by `$rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@rabbit1`, start your service by `rabbitmqctl start_app` and check `$rabbitmqctl cluster_status` to see weather you have joined the cluster or not.

I followed the [rabbitmq official documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) to setup the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

to change RabbitMQ sname/name behaviour you can edit the scripts:

- rabbitmq-multi
- rabbitmq-server
- rabbitmqctl

**Example**
In script rabbitmqctl there is the following piece of code:

```
exec erl \
    -pa "${RABBITMQ_HOME}/ebin" \
    -noinput \
    -hidden \
    ${RABBITMQ_CTL_ERL_ARGS} \
    -sname rabbitmqctl$$ \
    -s rabbit_control \
    -nodename $RABBITMQ_NODENAME \
    -extra "$@"
```

You have to change it in:

```
exec erl \
    -pa "${RABBITMQ_HOME}/ebin" \
    -noinput \
    -hidden \
    ${RABBITMQ_CTL_ERL_ARGS} \
    -name rabbitmqctl$$ \
    -s rabbit_control \
    -nodename $RABBITMQ_NODENAME \
    -extra "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks! I just figured it out a couple of hours ago and I'm working on compiling the full account of my problems to post as an answer (since I had several issues related to distibuted rabbitmq).

Answer (score -2):

**http://pearlin.info/?p=1672**

so you need to copy the cookie from the node you trying to connect

example :- rabbit@node1
           rabbit@node2

go to rabbit@node1 and copy the cookie from cat /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie

go to rabbit@node2 remove the current cookie and paste the new one.

on same node

> /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl stop_app
>
> /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl reset
>
> /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl cluster rabbit@node1

should do it.

same documented here.

http://pearlin.info/?p=1672

Comment: The link you posted `http://pearlin.info/?p=1672` is not english nor is it about programming.